# Node bot configuration issue

Tags: node.js, botframework

Bot running on local ubuntu 16.04 server begind the Nginx

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Restify listening to http://[::]:3978

I am able to connect to the service remotely with Channel Emulator, however when send a message in chat restify falls with error:

```
WARN: ChatConnector: receive - emulator running without security enabled.
ChatConnector: message received.
The Bot State API is deprecated.  Please refer to https://aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace with your own storage.

**Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:55531**
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

Any ideas what it is expect to find on 55531?

Same code works on windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection error is related to the [Emulator's](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator) built-in [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) server, and wheather or not the Eumlator is configured to use it based on your bot's deployment location.

You need to configure the App ID and Password in the Emulator to connect to remotely hosted bots. When you are testing the bot locally, you don't need the App ID/Password configured in the Emulator.

Also for reference, there is a (checkbox) setting in the Emulator called "Bypass ngrok for local addresses". Make sure it is checked when you are testing locally, and unchecked when you are testing remotely hosted bots (or bots in Docker containers locally).

[image: Emulator settings]